# Regex match from first uppercase character in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a camelcase string e.g. `thisIsCamelcaseString`

I'd like to remove the first lowercase characters from from the string.

To achieve this, I think I'm looking for a regular expression that will match from the first capital letter in the string to the end. In this example it would remove `this`, returning:

`IsCamelcaseString`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way to achieve it:

```js
console.log('thisIsCamelcaseString'.replace(/^[a-z]+/, ''));
```

This uses the `^` anchor which matches the string from beginning and then searches for the smallcase letters.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex

```
[A-Z]\S+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ulNlMO/1/)

This matches the first capital letter with [A-Z] and then any other non-blank characters with `\S+`.

If you want to match only letters you can use

```
[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+
```